# javafx: How to stop an object's background task running when the object itself is deleted from Observable List?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `Trade` object and whenever it is constructed, it kicks off a task in the background (i.e. say download currentPrice) and start running every 10 seconds.

When the `Trade` object is created, it is also added to a `ObservableList` .

**Problem:** When I delete the object from the ObservableList, I can see that the task (download currentPrice) is still running in the background, although the object is not in the `ObservableList` anymore.

1. Is the object actually deleted ?
2. **How can I stop the object's background task from running when the object itself is already removed from the ObservableList?**

My goal is to delete the object forever and stop its background task from running as well.

```
public class Trade{

....

private final ScheduledService<Number> priceService = new ScheduledService<Number>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Number> createTask(){
            return new Task<Number>() {
                @Override
                public Number call() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
                    return getCurrentPriceFromGoogleFinance();
                }
            };
        }
    };

    public Trade(){
        priceService.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(10));
        priceService.setOnFailed(e -> priceService.getException().printStackTrace());
        this.currentPrice = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(0);
        this.currentPrice.bind(priceService.lastValueProperty());
        startMonitoring();
    }


     public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty currentPriceProperty(){
         return this.currentPrice.getReadOnlyProperty();
     }

     public final double getCurrentPrice(){
         return currentPriceProperty().get();
     }

     // multi-threading
     public final void startMonitoring() {
         priceService.restart();
     }

     public final void stopMonitoring() {
         priceService.cancel();
     }

     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand garbage collector right, your object will live for some time before it gets collected even after you remove it from your list.

To stop the task, add [ListChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) to your `ObservableList`. You can get removed `Trade` and call `stopMonitoring()` on it. That could hopefuly stop the task.